# Access and Refresh tokens with AXIOS and .NET 5 Web API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a React application (with Redux) which uses Axios to communicate with our Web API.

We are using JWT access tokens and refresh tokens for security.

Our Web API's server side token generation code is based on this:

https://github.com/cornflourblue/aspnet-core-3-jwt-refresh-tokens-api

If you need to see our implementation I can arrange for that, but it differs very little.

The problem I think is with the axios interceptor implementation we have. When our access token has expired and needs refreshed, I don't think the response interceptor is behaving properly. But I don't know what to do to fix it.

How can I make axios, if a "Network Error" occurs with no response (typical response when the token has expired), call my refresh token Web API and retry the **previous** API call again?

At the moment, an error is being thrown by axios.

The authApi axios instance below is used by **every** web API call in our app, so that the bearer token is supplied in the request header:

```js
const authApi = axios.create({
    baseURL : API_URL    
});

authApi.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  store.dispatch({type: REQUEST_STARTED})
  return setBearerToken(config);
});

authApi.interceptors.response.use(
  (res) => {
      return res;
  },
  (err) => {  
    
    // Here I'd like onRejected to detect if access token has expired and if so, request a new token, then retry the last AXIOS operation.
    return onRejected(err);
  }
);



function setBearerToken (config){
  const state = store.getState(); // read redux store
  config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${state ? state.auth.token : null}`;
  return config;
}


async function onRejected(err){
  if (!err.config) return Promise.reject(err);

  if (err.config.url !== "/login") {
    if (err.response) {
      return handleErrorWithResponse(err);
    }
    else
    {
      return handleErrorWithoutResponse(err);
    }
  }

  return Promise.reject(err);
}


function handleErrorWithResponse(err) {
  const originalConfig = err.config;
    if (err.response.status === 401 && !originalConfig._retry) {
      return refreshAccessTokenThenRetry(originalConfig);
    } 
    // Irrelevant code elided

    return Promise.reject(err);
}


// This is the handler causing the error to propagate to the front end.
function handleErrorWithoutResponse(err) {
  if (err.isAxiosError && err.message === 'Network Error')
  {
    return refreshAccessTokenThenRetry(err.config);
  }

  return Promise.reject(err);
}


async function refreshAccessTokenThenRetry(config) {
  config._retry = true;

  try {
    await Authenticationservice.refreshAccessToken();
    return baseApi(config);
  } 
  catch (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
}
```

AuthenticationService.js is as follows:

```
class AuthenticationService {

    refreshAccessToken = async() => {
        const state = store.getState();

        // Note how baseApi uses a different instance of axios to that (authApi) above.
        // Could that be involved, somehow?
        const rs = await baseApi.post("/users/refreshtoken", {
            refreshToken: state.auth.refreshToken,
        });
  
        const accessAndRefreshTokens  = rs.data;
        store.dispatch({ type : NEW_ACCESS_TOKEN, payload : accessAndRefreshTokens });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not use your solution token solution, but you could:

- Fetch the token the first time
- Retrieve the expiration date/time
- Start a timer that call your `refreshTokenCallback` before the expiration date (take x time of margin)
- In the `refreshTokenCallback` you update the current token with the new one and start the loop again ...

Like that your calls will never failed because of your invalid token and should avoid you some troubled managing errors.